# Spring RESTful Web Service Issue

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, web-services

I'm trying to run this Maven sample project I've cloned from: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Instructions says that I should be seeing a "Hello World" message but all I can see is the error message below on the browser.

*Whitelabel Error Page*

*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.*

*Thu Dec 17 13:50:12 EET 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).*

Any ideas to fix this will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its error 404, Not Found. It means your service URL is wrong. Please provide the service url you are using to hit the Rest service. I have just imported the same project and able to run successfully. When hitting url http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=User and getting {"id":1,"content":"Hello, User!"}. Some tips 1. Import maven project from "complete" folder. 2. Just start springboot application by running Right click on->"RestServiceApplication" -->run as java. And hit the url  http://localhost:8080/greeting?name=User. Note: check the port on ehich ur tomcat server started.
[image: project in eclipse]
[image: Service call]

Answer (score 0):

Url which is open by default `http://localhost:8080/` your controller doesn't cover, either access `http://localhost:8080/greeting` or expand `@GetMapping(value = {"/greeting", "/"})` with the default path